# EPPlus sees comma as a dot

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, epplus

I am reading the excel file with EPPlus.
I get the data as decimal when I enter it as text in Excel.
I need to get my data as text.
I separate it with a comma.
The text I get will be separated by a comma.
I wrote: 1,4
EPPlus is worth: 1.4
I need to get all the data from the export as my text.
What can I do? 
There is an excel image in the picture.
What I want to do is; Take the data and split it.

as follows:

```
    string StickyBadge_Alphabet = IndexList.Where(w => w.Name == "STICKYBADGEIDS").FirstOrDefault().Alphabet;
    var DataCell = workSheet.Cells[StickyBadge_Alphabet + i];
    Vehicle.StickyBadgeIDs = string.IsNullOrEmpty(DataCell.Text) ? new int[] { } : DataCell.Text.Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Trim())).ToArray();
```

**I ask for your help.**

[image]

Comment: what does `EPPlus` have to do anything with it ?

Comment: It's difficult to give a useful answer to this question.  What is EPPlus? I'm guessing it is library you are using for excel import but it would be useful if you explained more.  I'm afraid I don't understand from your description what the actual problem is.  The only 'clue' I can provide is that interpretation of numbers is locale-specific and in some places "1.4" means 14/10 whereas in others "1,4" is used.  Perhaps you have a localisation issue?

Comment: EPPlus: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus (The excel file and the library that reads the data.
) There are various values in the same column.
For example;
Line 1: 1,4
Line 2: 3,4,2
Line 3: 5,1
Line 4: 1,3,6,7

That's what happens when I want to get a receipt.

Line 1: 1.4 (Dotted) (It comes in decimal.) Line 2: 3, 4, 2 (This comes as text.) Line 3: 5.1 (Dotted) (It comes in decimal.)Line 4: 1,3,6,7 (This comes as text)

I just want the to data come as text

Comment: That's useful information.  It sounds like the EPPlus library is automatically select the object type based on the string format.  Unfortunately I am not familiar with that library so can't help you further but I would expect there to be a way to either configure the library to treat every cell in a column as text or to get the raw text from a specific cell.

Comment: I set it to text in Excel. But it's still decimal. :( https://i.hizliresim.com/jylZQ9.jpg

Comment: Add the correct datatype to the cell and your own Excel localization will take care of the separator characters.